# Basic DNS and URL Redirect for just a web server

Tags: dns, configuration

I am unable to find the proper setup of DNS records with URL Redirect service for a basic web server where:

- Any URL with `www.Example.com` should go to server with IPv4 address `192.0.2.4`
- Any URL for `example.com` or `Example.com` should be replaced with a URL of `www.Example.com`.

  - I do not really understand forwarding versus redirecting. What I want is to transform any "example.com" request to a "www.Example.com" request (always using the 'www', and not respecting the naked 'example.com').
- No other services rendered on this server except the web server (and `ping` etc.). So no concern about email servers, FTP servers, etc.
- Sites will be accessed over HTTPS, hence with certificates.

Should it be:

- Type: **A Record**

  - Host: @
  - Value: 192.0.2.4
  - TTL: Automatic
- Type: **CNAME Record**

  - Host: www
  - Value: example.com
  - TTL: Automatic
- Type: **URL Redirect Record**

  - Host: @
  - Value: `http://www.Example.com/` Unmasked

Comment: DNS does not forward or redirect. It only ties the domain name with an IP address and a few associated records.

Comment: @closetnoc Well, yes, you are correct technically. But many DNS services also provide a URL Redirect service along with the DNS records. I edited to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You want an A record on host `www` pointing at your IP address. That will take care of `www.example.com`.

For `example.com` -> `www.example.com` you need a redirect. As noted in the comments, DNS on its own cannot redirect, but many DNS providers offer some sort of redirection service. The capabilities of these will vary a bit between providers. You may be able to setup a redirect on host `@` to www.example.com, which would do what you want. However, your provider may not allow you to have this in addition to the www.example.com A record (i.e. you might only be able to redirect the whole domain). In this case you would need to set an A record and handle the redirect yourself (how to do this will depend on what web server you are using - see [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85575/non-www-to-www-redirects) for an example of how to do it with Apache).

Also note that domains are case insensitive. There is no difference between `www.example.com` and `www.Example.com`, so you can't redirect from one to the other. Browsers will usually display them as lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "URL redirect record" in DNS.   To redirect a domain, you need enter the IP address of a web server that is configured to issue an HTTP redirect.

I would take the approach of putting the same IP address for both your apex record and your `www` record:

- `.example.com` A `192.0.2.4`
- `www.example.com` A `192.0.2.4`

Then on your webserver you can set up a virtual host that does the redirect and one that serves content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/example.com"
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Many web hosts don't allow you to edit your own virtual host files.  Those hosts typically have the bare domain and the `www` domain set up to be handled in the same virtual host.   In that case, you can just use some `.htaccess` rules to do the redirects

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]
```